# (C#) Quick way to operate on multiple Array items in sequence?

Tags: c#, arrays

C# newbie working off some tutorials.  Is there a way to run an identical command on every object in an array?

Here is my current (working) code:

```
     Guys[0].Cash += Guys[0].MyGuess.PayOut(WinnerNumber);
     Guys[1].Cash += Guys[1].MyGuess.PayOut(WinnerNumber);
     Guys[2].Cash += Guys[2].MyGuess.PayOut(WinnerNumber);
```

I'm looking for something that will do this:

```
     Guys[X].Cash += Guys[X].MyGuess.PayOut(WinnerNumber);
```

X = is first number on first runthrough, then 2nd number on 2nd runthrough, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several options:

[Plain old `for` loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte(VS.80).aspx):

```
for(int i = 0; i < Guys.Length; i++) {
    Guys[i].Cash += Guys[i].MyGuess.PayOut(WinnerNumber);
}
```

[`foreach` block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx):

```
foreach(var guy in Guys) {
    guy.Cash += guy.MyGuess.PayOut(WinnerNumber);
}
```

[`Array.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2.aspx):

```
Array.ForEach(Guys, g => g.Cash += g.MyGuess.PayOut(WinnerNumber));
```

These, for me, are in order of preference. Most will prefer the `for` loop because that is the familiar way of doing something to every item in array in sequence. It's close though between `for` and `foreach`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  The "for loop" method was in my tutorial book, but I was looking for something more like your 2nd two examples.  Glad I know what my options are.  Thanks much!

Comment: Worth noting that `foreach` and `Array.ForEach` will only work if the type is a `class`, not a `struct`. If the type is a `struct` then attempting to use `foreach` will cause a compile-time error, which is fine, but `Array.ForEach` will fail silently at runtime without updating anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Guys.Length; i++)
{
    Guys[i].Cash += Guys[i].MyGuess.PayOut(WinnderNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a not-widely documented idiom that you can actually do this with the foreach command, as long as this is a object[] construct:

```
foreach(GuyObject guy in Guys) {
   guy.Cash += guy.MyGuess.Payout(WinnerNumber);
}
```

Guess I should add LAMBDA version as well:

```
Array.ForEach(guys, guy => guy.Cash += guy.MyGuess.Payout(WinnerNumber));
```

Comment: Appreciate it!  I'm not quite up to LINQ yet, but hopefully I'll have use for that soon.  Also appreciate the explanation of foreach.

Comment: `ForEach` isn't LINQ. It's a static method on the `Array` class itself.

Comment: Ugg. Long day, I meant "Lambda version"